# "No useful address for host" VNC-Error

Tags: linux, vnc

I installed TigerVNC on 2 of my CentOS Linux-Workstations with the following command:

```
sudo yum install tigervnc -y
```

After rebooting both workstations, I did only execute the following command on one of the workstation:

```
sudo vncviewer
```

Now I inserted the ip-address of the other workstation and tried to connect to it.

**No useful address for host**

Does anybody have an idea to resolve that problem?

Thank you guys so much!

PS: I guarantee that the two workstations can communicate with each other (tested with ICMP --> Ping)

Answer (score 0):

So thank you guys for the detailed explanation....

The solution to this problem is to specify the display with "**:1**".

**192.168.1.1:1**